# Why do hamster bit the bars of the cage

Tags: hamsters

Hey can someone pls help me iv had my hamster for about a month Friday and she is still getting use to us but there is one think I can't stand is her biting her cage iv give her everything she has her wheel toys to bit and the food things to bit iv just give her carrot and she is still biting the cage I can be up this 3am again tonight pls help

Comment: Does your hamster have Hay? And how large is the cage? What kind of cage, and what kind of toys are there?

Answer (score 0):

Rodent incisor teeth grow continuously, and need to be worn down to balance that. If you don't provide suitable chewing material, they will chew whatever is available, including the cage.